# How to [temporarily] suppress "defined but not used" warnings?

Tags: haskell, ghc

When I prototype Haskell programs, I always get hundreds of warnings like this (not joking):

```
/Users/bob/SourceCode/course/is/expriment/LiftedSpine2.hs:70:15:
    Warning: Defined but not used: `ta'

/Users/bob/SourceCode/course/is/expriment/LiftedSpine2.hs:72:15:
    Warning: Defined but not used: `ta'

/Users/bob/SourceCode/course/is/expriment/LiftedSpine2.hs:77:26:
    Warning: Defined but not used: `v'
```

Is there anyway to remove these warnings temporarily?
I tried putting this in my .hs file:

```
 {-# OPTIONS_GHC -fno-warn-unused-binds -fno-warn-name-shadowing 
    -fwarn-monomorphism-restriction -fwarn-hi-shadowing
 #-}
```

Unfortunately, it does not work, and although I also tried to :set -fno-warn-unused-binds, it still does not work.

Many thanks!

Comment: I really wish the `OPTIONS_GHC` thing did work, but haven't gotten around to following up with figuring out the exact behavior, filing a ticket, etc.

Comment: Surprisingly nobody seems to have addressed the claims that OPTIONS_GHC doesn't work. I think the claim is false. The following works for me: {-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall -fno-warn-unused-binds #-}

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Another possibility, depending on your situation: I believe you can prefix identifiers with an underscore to suppress this warning.  So:

```
_x = 42
```

will not generate the warning if `_x` is not used.

Comment: Indeed. Why is that happening though?

Comment: I think because somebody decided it should. Sometimes you want to document the meaning of a parameter even if you don't use It.

Answer (score 19):

GHC has two warnings flags which can trigger `Warning: Defined but not used`.

You need some combination of the command line flags `-fno-warn-unused-binds` and `-fno-warn-unused-matches`.

Comment: If running `hdevtools` you have to prepend `-g` so that these work, like this: `hdevtools check -g-Wall -g-Wall -g-fno-warn-unused-binds -g-fno-warn-unused-matches source.hs`

Answer (score 8):

I usually use -w to suppress all warnings when I want get rid of some warning temporarily.

Comment: But then you lose out on other warnings you might've wanted to see.

Comment: Yes, but when I temporarily remove warnings it's temporary, so I'll get to see those warnings soon enough.

Answer (score 5):

I use a workaround for this:

I compile without warnings, but then I use `HLint` tool to display warnings for me. HLint has facilities to turn warnings separately.

Answer (score 1):

Using GHC 9.8.1, the following syntax is verified to work.

```
{-# OPTIONS -Wno-missing-export-lists #-}
```

Note that it’s `OPTIONS`, not `OPTIONS_GHC`, and `-W`, not `-f`. I showed a different warning being suppressed, but they all work the same way.